# System.IO.FileLoadException System.IO.FileLoadException Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my WPF application targeting .NetFramework 4.6
I have a button which is "bind" to a public `ICommand`

After launch of the application, when I click on the button I get the error

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

This happens intermittently.

Comment: Can you give more information as to under what circumstances this happens? For example, does it happen when you build for debug and not for release? Vice versa?

Comment: Don't try to fix DLL Hell by copying System.Runtime into your build directory.  That only produces more hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out my solution reference another project that reference a different version of the framework.. 
once i removed that it works